# Verbnet : vn.classids() returns 2 lists but I need to remove 1 of them

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

```
metaphor1 = " I run a race" 
from nltk.corpus import verbnet as vn
for word in metaphor1.split():
    if vn.classids(word) != []:
        start = set(vn.classids(word))
        print (start)
```

The above code will print out

```
['meander-47.7', 'preparing-26.3-1', 'run-51.3.2', 'swarm-47.5.1-1']
['run-51.3.2']
```

The first is the list of all of the verb senses for "run" but the second list is the one that gives the sense that is used in the sentence. I want to remove the first list and I tried to do so with

```
metaphor1 = " I run a race" 
from nltk.corpus import verbnet as vn

for word in metaphor1.split():
    if vn.classids(word) != []:
        start = set(vn.classids(word))
        remove = set(vn.classids('run'))
        final = list(set(vn.classids(word))-set(vn.classids('run')))
        print (final)
```

However this returns

```
[]
[]
```

What exactly is causing this issue and how do I fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop returns an empty list, `[]`, because the symmetric difference of a set with itself is an empty set.

You want to remove the third element of synset, `run-51.3.2`. You have incorrectly assigned the variable `remove` to the entire synset of `run`, not just one element.

**Try this**

```
import nltk
metaphor1 = STRING HERE
for word,pos in nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(metaphor1):
    if 'V in pos: #Another way to focus on only verbs
       return [sense for sense in vn.classids(word) if 'run' not in sense]
```

I used `pos_tag` to be explicit verbs. VerbNet might return an empty list even if the word isn't in the VerbNet databased even though word is functioning as a verb.

I used `word_tokenize` to make the code more general.

The code returns a list. Change `return` to `print` if you want to just print the variable to console.